# how can I arrange four objects into two rows and two columns?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there an easy way to take four objects that are in the same location? The objects are pasted on top of each other, and arrange them into two rows and two columns without scrambling them manually, selecting two, aligning them left, selecting another two, aligning them to the bottom, etc.

Comment: What do you mean with "objects"? Text, images, tables? What to do depends on what you have to use ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no on-click solution. But with the Align panel you can make it easier...

[image: align]

The "key object" is the top most object if multiple objects are selected.

Comment: The video is cute, but isn't that basically what I just said?

Comment: @plainclothes Don't know. Didn't see your answer until after I posted this. If duplicate answers are an issue, then there will be a great many people upset across all SE sites.

Comment: @plainclothes true, but Scott gets points for awesome sauce.

Comment: That screencast is pretty awesome. What tool are you using to make it?

Comment: I love this!!<!<!<!<!<

Comment: wish photoshop could do this...photoshop really needs some basic functionality in some areas

Comment: Great animation, but I would argue that shift arrowing a few times across and down is WAY quicker than this method. You also wouldn't lose the position of your first box.

Comment: @John That really depends upon your nudge setting. I keep my nudge options at a fraction of a pt.

Comment: @nachocab Screenflow on the Mac and Photoshop Extended :)

Comment: Agreed. Points for extra effort.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I'm aware of is via the Align panel.

[image]

1. Select the two top row items then click the top left item again to make it your "key object" or fixed reference point.
2. Enter your chosen gutter value in the `Distribute spacing:` field and click the horizontal spacing button.
3. Left align the first of your second row objects and follow the same approach to get the vertical space between it and the top row.
4. Repeat step 1 to get the space between your two second row objects.

Not very automated, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually enter their positions in coordinates at the top, otherwise holding shift and moving them into positions with the arrow keys shouldn't take more that 20 seconds to do. (move 2 to the left to make 2 columns of 2, then select one from each column and move them down)